# Xaml getting statusbar to dock in bottom

Tags: c#, xaml

I can't get my statusbar to show in the bottom. When I dock it to the bottom shouldn't it work this way?

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Open" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save As" />
            <MenuItem Header="Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <ToolBarPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Button>Næste</Button>
        <Button>Frem</Button>
    </ToolBarPanel>
    <RichTextBox DockPanel.Dock="Right"></RichTextBox>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">test</StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) the last child always fills the panel, regardless of what you set the `Dock` value to, unless the `LastChildFill` property is set to false (default is true). So either move the `StatusBar` above the `RichTextBox` or set the `LastChildFill` property to false.

**Update**: `RichTextBox` behaves a bit strangely, it appears it always fills the dock panel in your case, even if `LastChildFill` is set to false. If `RichTextBox` is replaced with another control then the behavior is as expected. I don't know enough about WPF yet to know why this is. But if you put your `StatusBar` above the `RichTextBox` everything seems ok.

Comment: This man has a correct in identifying the problem. However, the best solution in this case is to just add a <Grid> as the last child of the <DockPanel>

Comment: I swapped the 2 last around so its first the statusbar and then the richtextbar